# AWS lambda/api gateway does not redirect

Tags: java, spring, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a very simple spring route that im attempting to run on aws lambda. The route simply returns the text/string "redirect:/upload" instead of redirecting. I have the html file in the /resources/templates folder.

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String UploadPage2() {
        return "redirect:/upload";
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is from the return type of method: `String`.

You can do:

```
public RedirectView UploadPage2() {
    return new RedirectView("/upload");
}
```

**Second question**

To return an view on path `/test` with `GET` request, you need another method with same `path` but different `method`

```
@RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public ModelAndView testGet(){
    return new ModelAndView("uploadview");
}
```